# Pumping lemma for $a^nb^{2n+1}$

Tags: regular-language

I know how to solve pumping lemma for $a^nb^n:n\geq 0$.
But I don't understand how can I solve this example : $a^nb^{2n+1}:n\geq 0$.

I tried to solve it but I am not sure that I have solved it correctly or not?Could somebody please help me here?

I can show how did I solve it. But seriously I am not sure is it correct or not. Could you please give me the correct one if I am wrong.

**Question :** Prove that $a^nb^{2n+1}:n\geq 0$ is not regular.

Here is my answer.

> Assume L is regular. Then pumping lemma must hold. Let m be an integer in Pumping lemma.
>
> Let w=a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup> also in L. and |w|>=m
>
> By Pumping lemma w=xyz where |xy|<=m and |y|>=1
>
> According to pumping lemma w<sub>i</sub>=xy<sup>i</sup>z also in L for i=0,1,2,...
>
> Let i=2 then w<sub>2</sub>=xyyz.
>
> Let y=a<sup>k</sup> where 1<=k<=m and x=a<sup>q</sup> where 0<=q< m then z=a<sup>m-q-k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> w<sub>2</sub>=xyyz = a<sup>q</sup>a<sup>k</sup>a<sup>k</sup>a<sup>m-q-k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> = a<sup>m+k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> but this is not in L for any value of 1<=k<=m
>
> So we have contradiction with pumping lemma. so, our assumption that L is regular is wrong. So, L can not be regular.

Is this correct???

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You don’t really need $q$: $x=a^{m-k}$.